# Azure DevOps pipelines for Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-databricks

No idea what all from Azure databricks can be based on Azure DevOps pipeline. We are planning to use github as repository.

Like can Azure databricks be coded in file and then that file i can manage in git repo?

Can we use Azure DevOps CD pipeline for deployment in Azure Databricks?

Comment: Well first step is you could look up online resources, tutorials, documentations, etc using your favorite search engine.

Comment: I see no question here....

Answer (score 7):

> Can we use Azure DevOps CD pipeline for deployment in Azure Databricks?

The short answer is yes.

We could configure Azure Databricks workspace to use Azure DevOps and there is a task [Databricks Script Deployment Task by Data Thirst](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DataThirstLtd.databricksDeployScriptsTasks), which will give you the option of deploying scripts, secrets and notebooks to Databricks.

For the details info, you can refer to following document:

[CI/CD with Databricks and Azure DevOps](https://thedataguy.blog/ci-cd-with-databricks-and-azure-devops/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this - just wondering why there isn't an agent job created by Microsoft?

Comment: There are agent jobs created by Microsoft DevLabs that you can have a look into.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=riserrad.azdo-databricks